# ¿Como puedo llamar devuelta a estos valores ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

el problema que tengo es que no puedo traer los valores en formato json que estoy haciendo llamar desde la segunda página enviados a través de ajax, para poder asignarlos a a otro input en el mismo done, es decir.

Tengo el siguiente ajax

```
 function Cargar() {
    var Url = "ACTIONS.PHP";
    var id_Ticket_modal = document.getElementById("id").value; // obtengo la variable que deseo
    var arreglo = {
      "valor": id_Ticket_modal
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: Url,
      dataType: 'text', //no puedo convertirla en un json
      data: arreglo ,

    }).done(function(data , textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (console && console.log) {
          console.log("La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.");
          console.log(data)


          // document.getElementById('id_Ticket').value = data.id_Ticket;   //Esto es lo que no me funciona 
          // document.getElementById('estado').value = data.estado; 


          // $('div.modal').html(data); 
          // $('#exampleModal2').modal('show'); //Llamada al segundo modal                                
        }
    }).fail(function() {
      alert("Error al buscar datos");
    });
  }
```

bueno para explicar el código va a la otra página llamada ACTIONS.PHP, y trabajo con el post que mando es decir el "id_Ticket". en donde los trato y me manda el siguiente "texto". Y para que ya sepan con anterioridad no me deja enviar el dato como un json.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la imagen me los trae de manera de texto y los trato de transformar en json para poder llamarlos a través del mismo ajax, en donde sale este siguiente código en el ajax en la parte del "done".

```
       document.getElementById('id_Ticket').value = data.id_Ticket.valor;  
       document.getElementById('estado').value = data.estado.valor;
```

Y bueno la cosa que al llamarlos me sale NULL, y si tienen duda como los trabajo en la pagina ACTIONS.PHP ES DE LA SIGUENTE MANERA

```
$ticket_ID = json_encode($_POST['valor']); // LOS TRATO DE TRANSFORMAR EN UN JSON

$ticket = $GLOBALS['DB']->getTicket($ticket_ID); //OBTENGO LAS VARIBLES DEL TICKET


echo $ticket; // MUESTRO LAS VARIABLES
```

Al final no puedo traerlos como un json, siempre me los trae como un texto y no puedo trabajarlos hay alguna otra manera si no existe una solución?

Comment: Pero ¿por qué no pones `dataType: json` ?...

Comment: @FranciscoJavier no me deja me manda fail

Comment: que raro, pero si reemplazas "=>....string--)" por":" te queda casi un json

Comment: @Francisco son de tipo json originalmente por eso están de ese formato pero al traerlos del data del ajax me los reconoce como textos , es decir me trae todo como un Sting y no puedo trabajar dato por dato.

Answer (score 0):

Respondiendo para mi ayuda a tu futuro weeee

```
 function Cargar() {
    var Url = "actions.php";
    var id_Ticket_modal = document.getElementById("id").value; // obtengo la variable que deseo
    var arreglo = {
      "valor": id_Ticket_modal
    };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: Url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: arreglo ,

    }).done(function(data , textStatus, jqXHR) {
      if (console && console.log) {
          console.log("La solicitud se ha completado correctamente.");
          console.log(data.data)


          document.getElementById('id_Ticket').value = data.data.id_Ticket.valor.


          // $('div.modal').html(data);
          // $('#exampleModal2').modal('show'); //Llamada al segundo modal                                
        }
    }).fail(function() {
      alert("Error al buscar datos");
    });
  }
```

y en la página de actions es el siguiente código y al llamarlos a través de ajax te lo transforma en json para poder trabajarlos.

```
$ticket = json_encode($GLOBALS['DB']->getTicket($_POST['valor']));

echo $ticket;
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo funciona tu código. Tu respuesta será de ayuda para otros usuarios con un problema similar si explicas su funcionamiento. Puede que para ti sea obvio, pero para otros, no. Lee [answer]. No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.